# Resizing linearlayout container doesn't update onClickListner position of views contained within

Tags: java, android, android-layout, onclicklistener

I have a linearLayout with some cardviews. When the Activity is created, these cardViews get an onClickListern. This Activity has a button that can shrink said linearLayout. However, once shrunk the location of the cardViews no longer match where you interact with it. For example, if you have a cardView on the middle, left side of the screen. Than shrink the linearLayout. You have to tap where the cardView would be, as if the linearLayout wasn't shrunk. Trying to tap where the actual cardView is, does nothing. How do I reposition the the location and size of the onClickListner to match the new location of the cardViews? I'm not against changing my approach on how to resize the linearLayout.

Before Shrinking:

[image]

After shrinking:

[image]

### zoom_in.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fillAfter = "true">

<scale
    xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration = "1000"
    android:fromXScale="1"
    android:fromYScale = "1"
    android:pivotX = "50%"
    android:pivotY = "50%"
    android:toXScale = "2"
    android:toYScale = "2"/>

</set>
```

### zoom_out.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fillAfter = "true">

<scale
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration = "2500"
    android:fromXScale = "1"
    android:fromYScale = "1"
    android:pivotX = "50%"
    android:pivotY = "50%"
    android:toXScale = ".2"
    android:toYScale = ".2" />

</set>
```

### TreeActivity.java

```
   public class TaxaTreeViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
    private TaxonomyNode taxonomyTree = TaxonomyNodeUtil.getInstance().getTaxonomyTree();
        private BaseTreeAdapter adapter;
        private Button zoomInButton, zoomOutButton;
        private Animation zoomInAnim, zoomOutAnim;
    ...
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tree_view);
        ...
    
    adapter = new BaseTreeAdapter<NodeViewHolder>(this, R.layout.node) {...
        //Tree stuff}
    
    zoomInAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.zoom_in);
    zoomOutAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.zoom_out);
    
    zoomInButton = findViewById(R.id.treeZoomInButton);
    zoomOutButton = findViewById(R.id.treeZoomOutButton);
    
    zoomOutButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {treeView.startAnimation(zoomOutAnim)});
    zoomInButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {treeView.startAnimation(zoomInAnim);});
```

### activity_tree_view.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/zoom_linear_layout"
        tools:context=".TaxaTreeViewActivity">


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/treeZoomOutButton"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/treeviewContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <de.blox.treeview.TreeView
                android:id="@+id/treeview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"></de.blox.treeview.TreeView>
        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/treeZoomInButton"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_zoom_in"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/treeZoomOutButton"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_zoom_out"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: The animation actually doesn't change the view's position. It just moves them visually. You should use ObjectAnimator instead.

Comment: Object Animator did the trick!